# Regex with HTML tags and escaped characters

Tags: python, html, regex

I have this text:

```
<h5 class="subblocksubhead subsubsectionhead first"><b>Messaggi inseriti</b></h5>
<dl class="blockrow stats">
    <dt><b>Messaggi inseriti</b></dt>
    <dd> 81</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="blockrow stats">
    <dt>Media dei messaggi giornalieri</dt>
    <dd> 0.02</dd>
</dl>
```

and I'm trying to extract the `" 81"`  using this code:

```
regex_message_sent_num=r'Messaggi inseriti<.+>\n\t\t<.+?>(\s.+)<.+?>'
pattern_message_sent_num=re.compile(regex_message_sent_num)
results_message_sent_num=re.findall(pattern_message_sent_num,html_text)
```

I always get an empty list as output, whereas when I test the code [here](https://www.regex101.com/#python) I get the right extraction.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? The HTML comes from a webpage from which I'm trying to extract some visible data as exercise. I tested the regex on the HTML text saved from chrome browser.

Comment: *"Any idea what I'm doing wrong?"* - yes! You're trying to [parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761). Use **an actual HTML parser**, [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or something.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will use the tool you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an HTML Parser instead, like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Using the text search and the [`find_next_sibling()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <dl class="blockrow stats">
        <dt><b>Messaggi inseriti</b></dt>
        <dd> 81</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="blockrow stats">
        <dt>Media dei messaggi giornalieri</dt>
        <dd> 0.02</dd>
    </dl>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

label = soup.find("dt", text="Messaggi inseriti")
print(label.find_next_sibling("dd").get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints `81`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try to write new code as exemplified in your answer and use the HTML parser BeautifulSoup.